# How to select input elements and return result

Tags: javascript, forms, function, console.log

I have a form with firstname and lastname as input.
I want to return full name + other functions (which are working).
code looks like this:

```
const firstName = document.getElementById("fname").value;
const lastName = document.getElementById("lname").value;
    
function fullName(firstName, lastName) {
const full = firstName + " " + lastName;
return full;
    }
```

.
.
.

```
function myFunction() { 
document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = fullName(firstName, lastName) + a() + b() + c()
}
```

---

it returns only the value of a() + b() + c().

Bonus question:
I would like the console to log in this format:

```
fullName:
a()
b()
c()
```

I've tried:

```
//console.log(function(a, "\n",b, "\n", c));

//console.log(function({ a }, '\n', { b }, '\n', { c }));
        
//console.log(function(`${JSON.stringify(a)}
        ${b}
        ${c}`)); 
//console.log(function(`a is line 1
            b is line 2
            c is line 3`));
```

I have seen it works with strings or numbers, don't know how to make it work with functions.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an example.

```js
const firstName = document.getElementById("fname");
const lastName = document.getElementById("lname");
const fullNme = document.getElementById("fullNname");
const getName = document.getElementById("getName");

getName.addEventListener("click", () => fullNname.value = fullName(firstName, lastName)+" "+otherFunction())

function otherFunction() {
  return "otherFunction";
}

function fullName(firstName, lastName) {
  return firstName.value + " " + lastName.value;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="fname" name="fname" value="Takeshi">
<input type="text" id="lname" name="lname" value="Kovacs">
<button type="button" id="getName">
    get Name
</button>
<input type="text" id="fullNname" name="fullNname" value="">
```

Comment: This helped me fix my code. Thank you very much for helping! Sorry for the stupidity of it, I just started learning JS.

Comment: No problem! It is not stupidity... keep learning! ;) Please click on up arrow, if my answer was helpful.

Answer (score 0):

You can't just declare somewhere firstname and lastname in the script and hope it updates magicly.. You have to get the information right before you want to use them

```
function myFunction() {
    const firstName = document.getElementById("fname").value;
    const lastName = document.getElementById("lname").value;
    document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = fullName(firstName, lastName) + a() + b() + c();
    // console.log supports "format" and %o prints objects
    console.log("a is %o b is %o c is %o", a(), b(), c());
}
```